# C++ to_string function giving different results for float and int conversion depending on the prescence of an extra print statement

Tags: c++, string, tostring

I need to turn all primitive data types to the form char*, and I am trying to do that by using the function to_string, but when the array of char * is passed to a different function, the two number data types (int and float) output the same value.

This is the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "pythonInvoker.h"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char * types = "sif";
    const char * strin = "Hello World!";
    int num = 2851791;
    float point = 75.123123;

    const char* argv[] = {"", "multiply", "multiply", strin, (std::to_string(num)).c_str(), (std::to_string(point)).c_str()};
    int argc = sizeof(argv) / sizeof(char *);





PyObject* pyObject = invokeFunc(argc, types, argv);
return 0;
}
```

The array sent to invokeFunc is:

```
 multiply multiply Hello World! 75.123123 75.123123
```

but when I add this line right before the invokeFunc call, the array changes:
the line:

```
cout<<(std::to_string(num)).c_str()<<endl;
```

The output:

```
 multiply multiply Hello World! 2851791 2851791
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression `std::to_string(num))` returns a temporary object, and `std::to_string(num)).c_str()` is a pointer inside this temporary object. The temporary object "lives" as long as the statement in which it is used. Hence, after `const char* argv[] = {"", "multiply", strin, std::to_string(num).c_str(),...`, it goes out of scope and "dies" before you pass it to a function in a later statement. The result of accessing the pointer stored in `argv` then is undefined behaviour, one of which you are observing.

If you store the result of `std::to_string(num)` in a local variable, which's lifetime exceeds the subsequent function calls, it should work:

```
std::string numStr = std::to_string(num);
const char* argv[] = {"", "multiply", "multiply", strin, numStr.c_str(), ...}
....
PyObject* pyObject = invokeFunc(argc, types, argv);
```